# how can i make a css class with other

Tags: html, css

i have class call `"example1"` this class defines a background, and i want to create another class call `"example2"` to uses the same background on each `<li>` of class called `"example1"` how can i make it. My goal it's use the class like this

```
<ul class="example2">
    <li>some text</li>
    <li>another text</li>
</ul>
```

i tried like this

```
example2, .example1 li{

}
```

but it doesn't work
Thansk for your help

**UPDATE**

I modified the question because my question it not was what i want. I want to use the same background of example1 in each `<li>` of example 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply the concept of inheritance for CSS classes as we do in OOP. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576147/can-we-include-common-css-class-in-another-css-class) as I think it's the same thing you want to do. One way to use a single background declaration is:

```
.example1, .example1 li { /* define only the background here */ }
.example1 { /* everything but the background */ }
.example2 { /* anything */ }
```

**EDIT:** If you are going to use CSS3, then you can use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Good luck with IE for that matter. That's one navigator I learned to hate over the years.

Comment: hi and thanks for asking i modified the question because i have a mistake redacting the question

Answer (score 1):

Use *.class* for classes in css

```
.example2, .example1 li{

}
```

You just forgot to add a dot in front of your *example2*-class

Answer (score 1):

You can put a background on the `<li>` elements in your example like this:

```
ul.example2 li {
    /* your background settings */
}
```

the above targets only `<li>` elements inside an `<ul>` having class example2. If you want to use the same style on multiple elements you can separate them using comma's like this:

```
.example1,
ul.example2 li {
    /* your background settings */
}
```

Comment: hi and thanks for asking i modified the question because i have a mistake redacting the question

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, what you meant is you want the background image assigned to the class `example1` to be assigned to those `<li>` who are the children of an element assigned the class `example2`?

If that's the case, use:

```
.example1, .example2 li {
    background-image: url('/image/url/here/');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a background property defined in class `example1` and you want that same background property to apply to `li` elements of class `example2`. Is that correct?

If so, then this may be what you're looking for:

```
.example1, .example2 li {
  background: ....;
}
```

Please clarify if I am still misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Actually, this is the same as @ju5tu5's answer. I must still not understand what you're asking.