# "aliasing" two css classes together

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap to style tables, e.g.,

```
<table class="table table-striped main">
```

but the table that I want to style is actually generated programmatically by another tool that I don't control, and it already comes with its own table class tag:

```
<table class="foo">
```

I can include css style sheets though. Is there a way to alias "foo" and "table-striped" to be the same class in my own css?

Comment: Find `.table-striped {` in the `bootstrap.css` and change it to: `.foo, .table-striped`.

Comment: Or in your own stylesheet simply copy the `.table-striped` rules from Bootstrap and make a copy with the class `.foo`

Comment: @j08691 Sorry it's actually multi-class table.

Comment: use jquery (or vanila js) and find all tables with class `.foo` and add any bootstrap extra css classes you need, that way you dont have to duplicate css code her and there all the time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we include common css class in another css class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576147/can-we-include-common-css-class-in-another-css-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1:** You can modify your css so that the same effects apply to both classes:

```
.foo, .table-striped{ some css }
```

**Method 2:**

Instead of aliasing them, you can simply perform a search for all elements with class name "foo" and add the class name "table-striped" to them.

```
var tmp = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
for(var i=0, j=tmp.length; i<j; i++){
    tmp[i].className += " table-striped";
}
```

Keep in mind that this is using javascript.