# How do I combine the rules of several classes into a new mixin/class?

Tags: html, css, mixins

I have several CSS classes with elements that always use the same combo.
Is there a way in CSS (Not LESS or similar systems) to bundle several classes into one rule?
Pseudo code:

```
.a{
   margin 30px 0;
}

.b{ 
  padding:0 4px;
}

@bob{
  .a;
  .b;
}

...
...
<div class='bob'>...</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the classes `.a` and `.b` in the same element? `<div class='a b'>...</div>` ...  Alternatively you can do something like `.a, .bob { ... } .b,.bob { ... }` and just use `.bob` in your element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we include common css class in another css class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576147/can-we-include-common-css-class-in-another-css-class)

Comment: @Ricky the classes I want to bundle are coming from bootstrap. I can't use LESS (or similar) in this project.

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS does not allow for this (which is one of the reasons why LESS and Sass were created in the first place).